# Python requests call fails with HTTPS

Tags: python, json, ssl, https, python-requests

I am running a Flask restful API behind an NGINX web server on AWS. I am hitting that with a python module from my Pi.

Everything worked fine when I was using HTTP to make calls to the api. But I just locked down my api so only HTTPS is possible. I changed the UIRL used by my python module but it now fails. The code is quite simple...here is an extract:

```
jsonpkg = {'subscriberID': self.api_login, 'token': self.api_token,
              'content': speech_content}
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
r = requests.post(self.api_apiurl, data=json.dumps(jsonpkg), headers=headers)
```

The values are being correct set by the class init section. And I am importing the requests module at the top. Error messages indicate it is using python 2.7. However when I monitor the API I can see its not even hitting the server. I can point a browser to the api and its working fine.

Am I to understand the requests module in python 2.7 does not support https?

Are there additional parameters I need to send for https?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha! With a little more digging into the request module docs I found the answer. If I use the following

```
r = requests.post(self.api_apiurl, data=json.dumps(jsonpkg), headers=headers, verify=False)
```

then it works. So the issue is with verifying the cert. I am not quite sure why the browser gets by without this...but perhaps it does the extra stuff automatically. So I either need to NOT verify the cert or have a local copy(?) that can be verified.

---

Final Update:

I finally worked out how to concatenate my site certificate with the chain certificate (and understand why). This site [here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html#chains) was a great help. Also, once they are concatenated you will probably get a second error, which if you google it you will find is caused by the need for a carriage return after the first certificate and before the second (edit the resulting concatenated file with notepad). I then was able to return the post to using "verify=True" which made the warnings about no verification go away.

Comment: Either the python is old and does not support SNI (was implemented in 2.7.9) which might be needed by the site or the site is not properly setup and missing a chain certificate (browsers will often work around this problem). Check your site with [SSLLabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html) and look for chain issues or SNI requirement. Simply disabling certificate validation is not a good idea.